# how can i config my bossGroup and workerGroup?

Tags: netty

i want my netty server handle request with the lowest delay ,how to config it ?
now my config is :

```
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(512);
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(512);
```

i find that  many request cost too much time .. i have tried

```
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(200);
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(200);
```

but i does not improved .
my linux server has 8g memory and two i5 cpus .

Answer (score 0):

Using 512 sounds just plain wrong ... you should not need so many threads. The point of using NIO is to minimize the amount of resources (i.e. threads). If your requests take too long you maybe block the IO-Thread ? I would check with a profiler.

Comment: how to block the IO-Thread , i am finding the way for a long time  . is it the readtimeouthandler and the writetimeouthandler ?

Comment: If you do any blocking action for example an jdbc call.